# Determine average of every Nth value in columns of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum, mean

I have a dataframe with values for pressure, wind speed and temperature per hour for 12 years. With groupby(pd.to_datetime), I have calculated the average for each month over those 12 years. Now, however, I want to calculate an overall average for each month. With this I mean:

avg_jan = jan_2011 + jan_2012 + jan_2013 + ....

I thus need to calculate an average for the sum of every 12th value in each column in my dataframe. Does anyone know how to approach this. I have tried the df.mean() aproach. However, this simply gives the mean for all the values. Not the mean per month.

```
w_data1120 = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', skiprows = 31, usecols = ['# STN', 'YYYYMMDD', 'FH'], low_memory = False)
w_data2122 = pd.read_csv('filename_2.txt', skiprows = 31, skipfooter = 2760, usecols = ['# STN', 'YYYYMMDD', 'FH'], low_memory = False)
w_data1122 = w_data1120.append(w_data2122, ignore_index = True)

w_data_month = w_data1122.groupby(pd.to_datetime(w_data1122['YYYYMMDD'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.to_period('M'), as_index=False).mean()
```

Comment: can you provide example of input and output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example There is no need to solve it with the method you suggested, just provide an example and output and it will be easily solved.

Comment: Input is a csv file which contains the pressure, temperature, and wind speed data per 1 hour over a period of 12 years. The desired output is to obtain the average values for the pressure, temperature and wind speed per month over that same period.

Comment: It's not a difficult problem, so if you make an example into code, it will be solved. It's hard for us to make an example of code for solving your problem. read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make reproducible and minimal example.

Comment: I added the code I have up to now. The next step I want to make is to to determine the mean of the sum all averages for e.g. the month of january. So determine the average of every 12th value in the dataframe w_data_month

Comment: we do not have your csv file so it is not reproducible example. That's  third thing I'm saying, plz make reproducible example. Or provide `w_data_month.head(20).to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

*Asuming variable names from the picture uploaded...*

First, you need to add a column "month" to your dataset. You can use a similar method to the one on your image:

```
w_data1122['month'] = pd.to_datetime(w_data1122['YYYYMMDD'], format = '%Y%m%d').dt.month_name()
```

Now for every row, there is a column that states the month name without the year.

Now, to get the mean you are looking for, you group by the month name and take the mean:

```
result_df = w_data1122.group_by('month').mean()
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This approach works. Thank you Sergio